# JavaFX: Call method on specific time

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a way to simply get a method to run on a specific frame or time?
I've read up on the Timeline and Keyframe + KeyValue documentation and it seems overkill for what I am trying to achieve.
I'm trying to get something as simple as this, (refer to my pesudocode):

```
atTime(Duration.millis(2000)){
     myMethod();
   } //do this at the time 00:00:02
atTime(Duration.millis(3000)){
     myMethod();
   } //do this at the time 00:00:03
atTime(Duration.millis(5000)){
     myMethod();
   } //do this at the time 00:00:05
```

And I keep timing when my method is called until I want it to stop.
Is there a way to achieve this without using complicated methods revolving around keyframes and keyvalues?

Comment: There's almost nothing more to doing that with a `Timeline` than the code you posted. Just create the timeline with a bunch of `KeyFrame`s, e.g. `new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(2000), e -> myMethod())`

Comment: The 'KeyFrame' part is what threw me off. Theres a bunch of extra parameters in it such as an onFinish event and multiple keyValues.
Is there a way to create a KeyFrame purely as a timing point?

Comment: The `onFinished` handler is exactly what enables you to call a method (or execute some code) at the specified time. What's wrong with creating the `KeyFrame` the way I did in the comment?

Comment: I wrote the KeyFrame declaration a little bit differently than the one you commented but i just tried yours now. It works like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in a pretty simple way using a `Timeline`:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), e -> myMethod()),    
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3), e -> myMethod()),
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), e -> myMethod())
);

// If you want to repeat indefinitely:
timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

timeline.play();
```